# What’s going on with the time conversions on SO?

Tags: discussion, timezone

The current time as I was writing this is 16:21 (GMT+2) and for some reason 1:20:06 PM UTC appears as "21s ago" on SO. (The date is good, however.)

Isn't UTC = GMT? (1:20 pm UTC should be 3:20 GMT+2, giving a 1 hour offset meaning that 21 seconds ago should be 1 hour and 21 seconds ago.)

...I am probably missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only 13:56 UTC at the moment. I think you're mistaken about your time zone. You may be two hours ahead of "British time" but UK is on BST now, which is UTC+1, making you UTC+3.

GMT ~= UTC, so I don't think you're *really* GMT+2.

Where are you, geographically? I can go from a city name to a full Olsen time zone fairly easily :)

Comment: Actually I am in GMT+2 time zone but Windows is automatically adjusting the clock for daylight saving changes which makes the current time zone to GTB Daylight Time, which makes you right. Thanks!

Comment: Geographically I'm in Cluj-Napoca, Romania and I forgot about the daylight saving change. I WAS missing something after all :)

Comment: wouldn't UK be on BDT now, and BST in the winter?  or do you name it differently across the pond?

Comment: @Kip: In the UK there's GMT (Greenwich Mean Time) which we use in the winter, and BST (British Summer Time) which we use in the summer.

Comment: @Jon Interesting.  Here in the US it is xST (x Standard Time) in winter, and xDT (x Daylight Time) in summer.

Comment: Yes - I don't know what the abbreviations are like elsewhere, to be honest. Mind you, I don't believe the abbrevations are always consistent even in the US - I think there are different variations on EST/EDT depending on exactly where you are, for example.

Comment: For example, [around where Raymond Chen lives](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/03/09/10280090.aspx), PDT stands for "Pacific Daylight Time" and PST stands for "we're going to ignore the fact that words have meanings and throw the S in there just to attempt to sound awesome." (Note: this happens in every other US time zone, too.)